# external javascript file in component frontend view in joomla 3.x

Tags: javascript, joomla, components

I am developing a custom component for Joomla 3.x. I added an external JavaScript file to one of my components front-end views called "pages" located in \com_mycomponent\views\pages\view.html.php within the function display(). I am using this code in this function:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript(JURI::root().'media/com_mycomponent/js/gallery.js');
```

When I check with firebug I see the file has been loaded but the problem is with the ordering. As you see below it comes before jquery.min.js. I also tried to add this file in \com_mycomponent\views\pages\tmpl\default.php using the same code, but the same problem happened. This is what I get from firebug.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/tester3/media/com_mycomponent/js/gallery.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tester3/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tester3/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tester3/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js">
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if the `JHtml` method will deal with the ordering issue but best give it a try. So replace this:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript(JURI::root().'media/com_mycomponent/js/gallery.js');
```

with this:

```
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
JHtml::_('script', JUri::root() . 'media/com_mycomponent/js/gallery.js');
```

Comment: I tried your recommendation both in view.html.php and default.php but the problem still exists which is very strange!!!!

Comment: @Gaz - Try using `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');` before as shown above

Comment: It kinda worked this time, but it still comes before bootstrap.min.js and template.js

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem if it comes before *template.js* however to ensure it comes after *bootstrap.min.js*, see my updated answer.

Comment: I mean this the normal way of adding external js files to componets?

Comment: Yes, this is the recommended method for Joomla 3.x ;)